# Perl Regular Expression simplification

Tags: regex, perl, repeat, simplification

I want to simplify the following statement.

```
if($_=~/^([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])/)
```

Is there an alternate way I can write the above statement without repeating [0-9a-fA-F] n times ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
if($_=~/^([0-9a-fA-F]{5})/)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Quantifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

> {n}    Match exactly n times

```
if (/^([0-9a-fA-F]{5})/)
```

Similarly, you can use a POSIX character class

> xdigit Any hexadecimal digit
>   ("[0-9a-fA-F]").

```
if (/^([[:xdigit:]]{5})/)
```

Comment: +1 for `[:xdigit:]`, which conveys the intent of the code more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

or even

```
if( /^([0-9a-fA-F]{5})/ )
```